# readonly kubectl access for kubernetes cluster running on ec2 provisioned using kops

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

We've multiple k8s clusters which are used by many teams for their microservices. We've restricted the `kubectl` access to the limited members only. But many times we get a request for allowing `readonly kubectl` access.

Many on k8s clusters are running on `ec2` & provisioned via `kops`.
Version details :

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.13.0
Server Version: v1.11.6
---
$ kops version
Version 1.12.2
```

I tried to create a `test-pod` with `kubectl` installed in it which readonly `clusterrole` & `clusterrolebinding` attached. I can see that the `kubectl` from within the pod can have readonly access but it needs me to `kubectl exec` into the pod. So, I don't know how can I restrict this access ?

I have tried [this](https://medium.com/@rschoening/read-only-access-to-kubernetes-cluster-fcf84670b698) but still don't know how to restrict access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make users in whatever authentication system you are using and then set the role binding to be aimed at those users, not a service account. Service accounts are for services, not humans.